# Using flexmock on python modules

Tags: python, flexmock

I've been searching on internet to find an example of using flexmock on python modules, but all doc's seem to be for object/class. I'm wondering if it's possible to mock some variables returned by a module. What if that module calls another module?

ex.

```
def function_inside_function(id, some_string):
    test_log = {"id": id, "definition": some_string}
    return test_log

def function1(id):
    some_string = 'blah' + id  # i am totally bs-ing here
    log = function_inside_function(id, some_string)
    return log
```

so now I want to test each function separately by using flexmock to mock some values

back then when doing the same thing with an object, I could do (say the object is assigned to be `test_object`)

```
flexmock(test_object).should_receive('some_func').and_return('some_value')
```

where `some_func` is being called inside that object

but when I try to do the same with a module, I kept getting

`FlexmockError: <function function1 at some_address> does not have attribute function_inside_function`

I want to know if it's possible to use flexmock on modules, and, if yes. how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and trial n error, it turns out that I have to use sys.modules

say my module is imported from `path.to.module`, then the syntax would be

```
flexmock(sys.modules['path.to.module']).should_receive('function.of.object').and_return(response)
```

`function.of.object` is the function being called. For example, `requests.get`. using only `get` will not work.

response is the response you try to mock. in the `requests.get` example, the response would be a `requests.Response()`, and then you can use `setattr` to set the attributes if flexmock complains about it. (Is there a better way to do it?)